# Develop code for managed package objects in Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

We have a managed package. Is it possible to use Salesforce DX to write triggers and classes using objects provided by the managed package?

When creating a scratch org, there is nothing associated with the managed package in there so how can you develop code against objects that are part of the managed package?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Create a scratch org, and install your managed package

`sfdx force:package:install -i 04t... --targetusername jdoe@example.com` [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_cli.htm)

where `-i 04t...` is the package Id which you will find on any installation link of your package.

As with ordinary orgs, you will have to use the namespace for all your packaged objects.

E.g. `[Select id FROM myNamespace__MyCustomObject__c]`

It is also possible to create a scratch org [with your `myNamespace`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Does this work for Paid managed packages?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question or its intention but from a technical standpoint, there's no difference between a managed paid or manageded free package.